# Scripting using Webdrive sampler in Jmeter for Browser rendering Testing, but stuck at Windows Authentication

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need a help or code snippet which help me to resolve problem, I am using Webdriver sampler to get the  rendered response time of  application, while scripting the login part, I got stuck with Windows Authentication popup, can some one help me how to write the code  or function to be called for the same.I am attaching the pop-up window. Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your popup window is very nice but unfortunately we cannot provide a comprehensive answer without knowing what exact authentication is being used under the hood.

In any case you need to supply valid [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header. Current stable version of the [WebDriver Sampler 3.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/3.3) comes with [Selenium API 3.141.59](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/3.141.59) and this Selenium version doesn't provide any possibility to control browser headers.

1. In case of [Basic HTTP authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) you can embed the credentials into the URL, for example you have:

   ```
   WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
   ```

   and you need to change it to:

   ```
   WDS.browser.get('http://your-username:your-password@example.com')
   ```
2. In case of [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) or [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) the process of generating the header is a little bit harder and you will need to do some [Groovy scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) in the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) for this. Once you get the header value you will need to pass it to the browser and the easiest way of doing this is probably using [BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) which can be started and controlled programmatically from the aforementioned JSR223 Test Elements.